# Relation between range and kernel of a linear operator

Tags: hilbert-spaces, operator-theory

Let $S = I - T$ where $T$ is a compact linear operator on a Hilbert space $H$. Why is it that the range of $S$ is equal to $S((\ker S)^{\perp})$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

let $x \in H$. As $\ker S$ is closed, we have $H = \ker S \oplus (\ker S)^\bot$, so write $x = x_1 + x_2$ with $x_1 \in \ker S$, $x_2 \in (\ker S)^\bot$. Then 
\[ Sx = Sx_1 + Sx_2 = 0 + Sx_2 = Sx_2 \]
So we have $Sx \in S\bigl((\ker S)^\bot\bigr)$ for every $x \in H$.

As you can see, this relation doesn't depend on the fact, that your $S$ is a compact pertubation of the identity, it holds true for every $S \in L(H)$.

Hope this helps,